# Is there any way to clear console output while using scala interpreter?

Tags: scala

I am using `scala` interpreter in console, is there way to clear the console?

Comment: That depends on your terminal. Possibly Ctrl-K or Ctrl-Shift-K?

Comment: For linux (maybe MAC too), Ctrl - L

Comment: Is `:reset` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Chirlo CTRL + L worked for me on Windows. Thanks.

Comment: `:reset` resets all the interpreter state. I want my console to be cleared.

Comment: @Chirlo please, post it as full fledged answer, so Fahad could accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>